# UITableView not showing any data

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am making an app in which i am using view based application.
My first view is a simple view controller class. there are some buttons in that view.
When i tap button , i want tableview.
so i am taking UITableViewController subclass.

what i am coin is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSBundle *bundle =[NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"cases" ofType:@"plist"];
    listfile = [[NSArray alloc ] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
   [self loadView];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSArray *temp = [listfile objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
   NSLog(@"Count : %@" , cell.textLabel.text);
return cell;
}
```

But, i can't see any data . it shows blank table only.
I am doing anything wrong??

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should implement following methods in your `UITableViewController`:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in section. 
    return [caselist count];
}
```

And

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Oops..!! Thanks Nekto.. i just forgot to set `return 1`